# Rails: What's the advantage/disadvantage of putting scripts and stylesheets directly in public folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, requirejs, assets

So that I could take advantage of all the already well developed front-end tools like requirejs, bower and grunt... It's just that so many of them somehow get crippled going with rails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's just that so many of them somehow get crippled going with rails

**Pipeline**

The reason is **you're not meant to use the likes of [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) etc with Rails**. Rails' asset pipeline is only meant to contain the files which can be precompiled & used directly in your application:

> The asset pipeline provides a framework to concatenate and minify or
>   compress JavaScript and CSS assets. It also adds the ability to write
>   these assets in other languages and pre-processors such as
>   CoffeeScript, Sass and ERB.

This will typically mean compiled third party JS/CSS files, and your own application JS/CSS files. I don't see how something like Grunt would provide any benefit to this? All it does it create a way for you to manage dependencies, versioning & source of particular assets?

--

**Public**

Using the files in your `public` folder isn't such a big deal. One of the most prominent things it *does* do is to exclude those particular files from the [file digest processs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark), allowing you to use the likes of [endpoints](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communication_endpoint) (scripts) which can be accessed by other services (outside the scope of `routes.rb`)

A good example of this is when we created an analytics system, and put the `analytics.js` into the `public` folder, so all the widgets could access it. This allowed other sites to access this file, regardless of the state of the asset pre-compilation.

One caveat to this would be you *could* perhaps have some way to store a "pseudo" file in the public folder, with it routing dynamically (with ERB) to the precompiled equivalent, but I've got no experience with this

--

**Pipeline**

The benefits of keeping your assets inside the `asset pipeline`, as stated by `gwcoffey`, are:

- They will be compiled as you design (I.E primarily into `application.js`, but also into any other files you define too)
- You don't need to worry about versioning (every `precompile` is basically a way to better the version without worrying about `grunt` etc)
- You can include as many dependencies as you want - meaning you're able to create a totally modular set of assets which can be used throughout your app; rather than single scripts which will have their own dependency base

---

**Recommendation**

Unless you maintain third-party scripts which need dependencies to run, I would not recommend using `Grunt` for Rails. If you develop your own JQuery / Javascript scripts, by all means run them through `Grunt` etc; but for use in your app, I'd steer clear

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 4):

Primary advantages:

1. It is easier to load third party scripts this way. It is always possible and sometimes easy to put these through the asset pipeline, but it is also often tedious and you lose bower.
2. Scripts in `public` will not be digested, so they can be loaded by non-rails pages easily. For example, you use a javascript file on your site, and also need to load it on another, e.g., PHP site, or need to allow other people to load your script for an embedded API, etc... then you'll need to serve from `public`.

Primary disadvantages:

Because you're not using the asset pipeline you lose:

1. Asset combining and compression. Asset pipeline CSS and Javascript will be loaded in a single HTTP request each, and the content can be minified. This makes first page load on your site faster, especially if you have lots of client code or a site that needs to be super snappy for occasional visitors.
2. Digesting. The asset pipeline protects you 100% from cache vagaries and potentially having different users seeing your site with different version of your assets. Once you deploy, *every* visitor will get the new assets.
3. Relatively automatic etagging. Once those visitors get the new assets, their clients will generally cache them for a long time. Rails can afford to let assets cache essentially forever because digesting ensures you're not punished for this later.

So there are pros and const both ways and neither is right or wrong.

Comment: You don't lose assset combining or compression by using Grunt/Gulp in place of the Asset Pipeline, you move the responsibility to the Grunt or Gulp. Both build tools can easily handle these tasks.